# Change angle of 3 sprites and make it look smooth/realistic

Tags: objective-c, xcode, math, cocos2d-iphone, geometry

I have 3 sprites that all have the same angle, so I'm just going to say arm sprite.
Arm sprite's angle, at the moment, is equal to one point1 (60,60 but this does not matter)
to another point2, the point where the player thumb pressed.

During the ccTime function I update everything, the angles and stuff. So whenever the user touches a spot on the screen, the angle is immediately changed and the arm's angle is equal to the vector from point1 to point2.

I don't want the angle change to take .016 seconds to complete (ccTime gets called every 1/60'th of a second). What I want is for the angle to increment/decrement faster/slower depending on how far away the new vector is from the current vector. Basically I want the arm to raise/lower at a certain speed, maybe accelerate a bit, depending on the vector.

I've tried many times to make it work, but I'm not getting anywhere. Please help me, rotation can go from 90 degrees straight up to almost 180 degrees straight down (the angles in cocos2d are changed, however, so I had to add 90 here and there).

If you need anymore information, just leave a comment and I'll give you the info asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the new angle as a `destinationAngle` then on your update loop:

```
//Instead of checking for equality, you might want to check the angle is close enough, e.g. if they are withing 1 degree of each other e.g.(if (abs(destinationAngle - angle) < 1)
if (angle != destinationAngle)
{
    //move towards destination
    angle += ((destinationAngle - angle) / 10.0f);
}
```